# I am tired of editing questions and adding the api to the start of title

Tags: discussion, edits

Lots of users ask a question in the form of "How to do stuff", When it should be "API - How to do stuff". It is mentioned in [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) but who reads that right? Am i the only person who cares about all of the questions getting unsearchable everyday? So "Questions that may already have your answer" automatic search is bound to be useless?

Comment: The titles should _not_ be of the form “API - How to do stuff?”, but rather “How to do stuff using API?” if the API should be mentioned at all. Information available in the tags should be _removed_ from the titles. Most titles like “How to foo the bar in language?” should be “How to foo the bar?” _tagged_ with “language” anyway. Also, don’t _just_ edit the title! Edit the _entire_ question. There’s so much other noise to be removed or formatting to be fixed.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the help center. I can understand why, but it's not about always having the API in the title, but having it there naturally when it's part of a sentence. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/230506

Comment: For what it's worth, it's good that you checked in about this. It makes sense to double check when you think you're seeing something done wrong a lot so don't take the down votes as an indication that you shouldn't have asked at all.

Comment: "So "Questions that may already have your answer" automatic search is bound to be useless?" - Yes and no. Tags are (or should be) already taken into account for determining what those should be, but there are some cases where not having the tags shown there will lead you to irrelevant questions.

Comment: Unlike James, I can't understand why someone may interpret the how-to-ask guide like that. Can you explain? If it helps, make a [meta-tag:feature-request] to change the wording. /// _[Meta votes don't affect reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), by the way._

Answer (score 24):

You're seeing the side effect of what the site *adds* to its URLs when referenced from a search engine.  It has been long standing site policy to [not add tags in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/175248), so by adding those tags in titles, you're actually running *counter* to site policy.

Comment: ...and like a bolt of lightning the community has rushed in to fix most, if not all of the poorly edited titles.  I suppose we're fortunate that it was made this visible this quickly.

Comment: [This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20949712) didn't add the language tagging. That was already there (and is still there after the rollback). OP added the specific error message to the title, which seems better than "odd behavior".